# How to display mysql records as preselected checkboxes?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table column called post_tags within a table called posts where assigned tags are stored separated by the @ symbol. I also have a table called tags where all tag names are stored. I would like to design my database in a more normalized way but for the purpose I am trying to achieve this is the easiest option.

Anyway, I want to display on the screen all the entries from the tags table as checkboxes, so I do:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY name");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $tag = $row['name'];

        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='tags[]' value='$tag' />\n";

    }
```

Next I want to have the tags that are assigned to a particular post be preselected. For example, if I have a post with the following in it's post_tags column:

> party@beaches@dolphins@

I want the "party", "beaches" and "dolphin" checkboxes to be checked by default (while the checkboxes for the other options are unchecked). How can this be done?

Comment: I'm not sure that you want to have a column like post_tags instead of using an intersection table. But if you really do you will just need to do more processing when pulling data out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is see if there is any existing data. So run that query and put the result of that table cell into lets say `$checkedstring` if not then put your default string in.

```
<?php
$checkedstring = "party@beaches@dolphins@";
//Pull from DB if exsists and set $checkedstring to that value
///
$checkeditems =  explode ( "@" , $checkedstring);
$checked = array();
foreach($checkeditems as $item)
{
  $checked[$item]=true;
}    

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY name");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
    $tag = $row['name'];
    $checkedstatus = '';
    if($checked[$tag])
    {
      $checkedstatus = "checked='checked'";
    }
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='tags[]' value='$tag' $checkedstatus />\n";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try the two results and the `in_array()` function.

```
<?php
$tags = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY name");
$post_tags = "party@beaches@dolphins@";
$arr_tags = explode("@", $post_tags);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $check = in_array($arr_tags, $row['name'])? 'checked="checked"' : "";
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="'.$row['name'].'" '.$check.' />';
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**
Because of Jeff question on performance, I looked for faster solutions and using `isset()` is faster so this would do a faster lookup of the values. the `array_flip()` is 3 time less taxing than `in_array()`:

```
<?php
$tags = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY name");
$post_tags = "party@beaches@dolphins@";
$arr_tags = array_flip(explode("@", $post_tags));

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $check = isset($arr_tags[$row['name']])? 'checked="checked"' : "";
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="'.$row['name'].'" '.$check.' />';
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the overhead of the in_array function? Is it scanning the whole array everytime?

Comment: I tested on my machine with medium size query results and it ran in .25 seconds

Comment: Your update looks great, when I looked more at the in_array it would scan the array each time through the loop so as the # of tags grows it would have problems but the flip and isset seems much better.